# auto_increment by group

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is there a way with MySQL (5.0 specifically) to have an auto_increment field who's value is based on a grouping column?

Example:

```
id  name   group_field
1   test   1
2   test2  1
1   test3  2
2   test4  2
1   test5  3
2   test6  3
```

I'd like to not have to go through any 'crazy' methods to achive this, but will if necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For MyISAM and BDB tables you can have an [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) field as a secondary part of key, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   group_field INT NOT NULL,
   name        VARCHAR(128),

   PRIMARY KEY(group_field, id)
);
```

Here's what the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) says about this

> In this case, the generated value for
>   the AUTO_INCREMENT column is
>   calculated as
>   MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE
>   prefix=given-prefix. This is useful
>   when you want to put data into ordered
>   groups.

Comment: As the manual only mentions MyISAM and BDB, I would guess not. See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT has to be on the primary key - if you attempt to create a table where you use it outside the key, you'll get error 1075 "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: Is this safe for multiple concurrent inserts?

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html for more depth on InnoDB handling of auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about [composite primary keys](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?125,75814,75814)?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with trigger on insert, setting max(id) from table group by group_field having group_fileld = @inserted_group;