# Insert a value based on a users location

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySql, Is it possible to do an insert based on something? In my case, I'd like to do an insert depending on the users location. Those locations are like US, UK, AU, CA etc.
So if the location is US i'd like to do 1-0001, 1-0002 etc, for uk 2-001, 2-002 etc.

Maybe by using case of something like that this could be possible?

My current insert goes like this:

```
insert into prodClassifieds (userId, userName, classStatus, classCountry, classId)
   select
     $userId, 
     '$userName', 
     1,
     '$userCountry',
     IFNULL((MAX(classId)+1) ,0)
   FROM prodClassifieds
```

EDIT: I can leave out the - in 1-0001. Also the MAX(col) is MAX(classId) not the one I originally posted. The next value is 1 + the current value that's there.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with a `CASE`. Which value are you trying to modify? Which column results in `1-0001`?

Comment: Put the location values into a table and join

Comment: If you are trying to construct those for `classId`, that is going to be more difficult since the `MAX()+1` is subject to problems from race conditions... Let us know how these will be used, and we can help.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski classId

Comment: @Norman Is this for a one-time data load, or will it by constantly updated from a live site?

Comment: See also [auto-incrementing by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677542/auto-increment-by-group) (since that is sort of what you are attempting)

Comment: What is the field you wanna insert this calculated value into ?

Comment: It will be constant updated from a live site. I can forgo the - in there.

Comment: @Norman This is going to be complicated then. Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB? If it is MyISAM, you can use the AI per group as I linked earlier but consider if you _really_ need this the way you are asking.  Perhaps you could just use a regular auto_increment and when you _query_ it, concatenate on the country prefix rather than store it that way.

Comment: Its MyISAM. Looks like i'll have to do this with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible,

```
insert into prodClassifieds 
(userId, userName, classStatus, classCountry, classId) 
select $userId, '$userName', 1,
'$userCountry', 
 case when userCountry='US' then 
MAX(sc_stack_id)+1 else 0 end
FROM prodClassifieds
```

U can add several conditions as per your need

Comment: It is the last column (the `IFNULL()`) which the OP wants to apply this pattern.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but this will always gives the same result for all countries right??

Comment: That's why this is complicated, per my comments above.  You can't just add 1 to a MAX() aggregate (especially without a GROUP BY).

Comment: yeah @MichaelBerkowski thanks for guiding. Will group by country will solve the purpose?

Comment: It will work some of the time, but if 2 queries insert at the same time, a race condition could cause the values to become out of sync or the same value for MAX()+1 to be inserted for both.

Comment: My "answer" is that I don't think this is a very good idea to begin with, and might be better off reengineered not to depend on increments per group :)

Comment: right right. Thanks man. Am deleting my answer since this will not solve the purpose. Happy new year.. Keep rocking :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE WHEN as follows:

```
insert into prodClassifieds (userId, userName, classStatus, classCountry, classId)
   select
     $userId, 
     '$userName', 
     CASE '$userCountry' WHEN 'US' THEN 10000 WHEN 'UK' THEN 20000 ELSE 90000 END CASE
     + 1,
     '$userCountry',
     IFNULL((MAX(sc_stack_id)+1) ,0)
   FROM prodClassifieds
```