# MySQL auto increment with sub index

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables, `jobs` and `job-parts` for which there are several job parts for each job referenced back using a `job_id` column.

The `jobs` table has the normal auto-increment on the `id` column which I'm using as the job number. So currently I pull the job parts out like follows:

> SELECT jobs.id, job_parts.id FROM jobs,job_parts WHERE
>   job_parts.job_id = jobs.id;

What I need to do is set up some sort 'auto increment' on the `job_parts` table, but one that resets for each different id on the first table, resulting in combined job references that look like

> 1.1, 
>   1.2, 
>   1.3,
>
> 2.1, 
>   2.2, 
>   2.3, 
>   2.4
>
> 3.1, 3.2 ... and so forth.

Ideally I'd like to be able to delete parts from the second table and the part `id` column to retain the numbers that were originally assigned when the parts were inserted, just like auto increment does normally.

Anyone know a nice clean way to do this with a SQL statement?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered here on SO. Either use triggers with innodb table engine, or you need to use myisam. But it is better if you do not do it at all.

Comment: @Shadow - Thanks, are you able to point me at the previously asked question? I did quite a few searches with the stuff I found not quite being the same situation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Shadow.

Comment: Here is one for myisam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677542/auto-increment-by-group

Comment: Don't forget to read the (not-accepted) answer to the duplicate that says: "Don't".

Comment: If you search for "MySQL autoincrement per group", then you will find many more.

Comment: As always, half the problem is knowing what to search for!